# TSQL: Multiple rows into single column in query result

Tags: t-sql, join

I feel I am missing a simple T-SQL answer to this question. I have a Measurements table, and an Activity table related by MeasurementID column, and there are at least 3 activities (sometimes more) related to a single measurement.  How do I construct a query such that the output would look like this:

```
Measurement ID         Activities
      1                 Running:Walking:Eating
      2                 Walking:Eating:Sleeping
```

I would also be satisfied if the output looked like this:

```
Measurement ID       Activity1    Activity2     Activity3
      1              Running      Walking       Eating
```

Is there a simple single query way to do this, or must I use (shudder) cursors to do the trick?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Comment: @juergend the table doesn't hold multiple values in a column, he just wants a query that will display that result for some reason.

Comment: For the first requested output, here is a duplicate:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for the two duplicates, I tried to search but missed those two. The second was very useful, close to what I needed, and what I need in the future. Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no `GROUP_CONCAT()` in T-SQL. There is a trick to simulate it, though:

```
SELECT
  MeasurmentID,
  Activities = REPLACE((SELECT Activity AS [data()]
                        FROM MeasurmentActivities
                        WHERE MeasurmentID = ma.MeasurmentID
                        FOR xml path('')), ' ', ':')
FROM
  MeasurmentActivities AS ma
GROUP BY
  MeasurmentID
```

Comment: This approach works for me. I can expand on the concept for sure.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I tweaked it slightly as the data I was trying to concatenate included spaces. My solution was to add a pipe to the SELECT and then replace that

`Activities = REPLACE((SELECT Activity AS [data()], '|'
                        FROM MeasurmentActivities
                        WHERE MeasurmentID = ma.MeasurmentID
                        FOR xml path('')), '|', ':')`

Comment: worked great.  I added [data()] and it removed xml syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance the number of activies by measurement, you can try the [PIVOT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx) operator.

Otherwise there is no easy way to do it.

If you can, I would suggest you to "horizontalize" the rows on your application-end.

If that is not an option, the only way I suppose would work in Transact-SQL is to convert your result in XML output and tweak it using XPATH queries.